# Parsing JSON when webpage returns []

Tags: android, json

I have some problem parsing JSON. The main idea is to find a data in SQL database by url:

```
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url + "?numer=" + number);
```

And then parse it. Everything goes fine, till I want to find a data which not exist in a database. Webpage returns "[]" and my android app returns error "Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject".
Here is a piece of code which I use.

```
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        Log.e("Znacznik", "Przed żądaniem http");
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("Znacznik", "Przed odczytem bufora");
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        Log.e("Znacznik", "Przed parsowaniem");
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        Log.e("Znacznik", "Przed returnem: "+jObj);
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

Comment: Whats the error? If there's no data, its right give this exception. You can use `try - catch` statment to alert, by a toast message, the user.

Answer (score 0):

So, why don't you just return `null` when exception is caught.

```
try {
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    return null;
}

Log.e("Znacznik", "Przed returnem: "+jObj);
// return JSON String
return jObj;
```

Comment: jObj is already null, so it changes nothing.
Problem appears after I return null.
     JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url + "?numer=" + szukanyNumer);

Answer (score 0):

Server should return `{}` in this case.

If it is not possible to change behaviour of server, you may try `JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(json)` and check what is type of `tokener.nextValue()`. It will be either `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`.

Answer (score 0):

in your response top root is json array, It should be first parse Json Array. 
Log your json response and see the response.

```
[]=> means Json Array
{}=> means Json Object
```

If the root one is [ ] means json Array parse it first

```
try {
           JsonArray array= new JsonArray (json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
```